# how can i print 2 or more values in array concept

Tags: python, arrays, dart

My code is like this:

```
main(){
var courselist = ["dart","flutter","swift","R"];
print(courselist[0]);
}
```

But I want to print my output as like this .. 'dart' and 'R'
How can I print 2 or more values in array concept?

I have tried doing like this:

```
print(courselist[0],[3]);
print(courselist[0],courselist[3]);
print(courselist[0] & [3]);
```

My Code:

```
main(){
var courselist = ["dart","flutter",24,0.45];
print(courselist[0]);
}
```

Error:

```
Harish@Harish:~/Desktop/dartfiles/Basics$ dart 01var_datatypes.dart 
01var_datatypes.dart:26:20: Error: The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '[]'.
print(courselist[2][0]);
                   ^^
```

Comment: First thing your code is not a valid Python code. With correct code, your second try: `print(courselist[0],courselist[3]); ` works.

Comment: Read [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/String-class.html) how the string manipulation in dart works

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `courselist[i]` to print ith index entry of the list. You need to write `print(courselist [0], courselist [3])` to print each of the entry. Writing  `print(courselist [0],[3])` or `print(courselist [0]and[3])` will not work. If you have large number of indices to print then you can avoid writing multiple times by iterating over a list:

```
vals=[0,3]
for val in vals:
    print(courselist [val])
```

You need to use correct PYTHON code for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display two variable in fluttet(dart) as you add tag you have can do as mention below.

```
print('Something ${variable1} ${variable 2} ');
```

You can also add whatever text you want at anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Within a quoted string you can build your output by evaluating expressions and variables.
Expressions surround them with ${expr}. Variables just prefix with $. E.g. $varname,

```dart
main() {
  var courselist = ["dart", "flutter", "swift", "R"];
  print("Dart Course: ${courselist[0]},  R Course: ${courselist[3]}");

  num grade = 10;
  print("Amount $grade");
}
```